# Django Issue: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I am completely new to Django. I created a class:

```
from django.db import models
from cqlengine import columns

class Rsvpstream(models.Model):
    venue_name = columns.Text()
    venue_lon = columns.Decimal(required=False)
    venue_lat = columns.Decimal(required=False)
    venue_id = columns.Integer()
    visibility = columns.Text()
    response = columns.Text()
    guests = columns.Integer()
    member_id = columns.Integer()
    member_name = columns.Text()
    rsvp_id = columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    rsvp_last_modified_time = columns.DateTime(required=False)
    event_name = columns.Text()
    event_time = columns.DateTime(required=False)
    event_url = columns.Text()
    group_topic_names = columns.Text()
    group_country = columns.Text()
    group_state = columns.Text()
    group_city = columns.Text()
    group_name = columns.Text()
    group_lon = columns.Integer()
    group_lat = columns.Integer()
    group_id = columns.Integer()
```

When I run this code, I got the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Users/hpnhxxwn/anaconda/envs/magenta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 105, in **new**
>       app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)   File "/Users/hpnhxxwn/anaconda/envs/magenta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 237, in get_containing_app_config
>       self.check_apps_ready()   File "/Users/hpnhxxwn/anaconda/envs/magenta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 124, in check_apps_ready
>       raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Can someone please advise how to proceed?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Hi nik_m, I am new to this, so am reading the document for the settings.py. I made a settings.py, and tried a run, but it complains about mising SECRET_KEY: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Comment: So, do you have a `SECRET_KEY` in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: I set it to "", and hoping the compiler won't say that message again, but still gives me the same error.

Comment: You must not set it to an empty string! The first time you run `django-admin startproject project_name`, Django automatically creates a `settings.py` for you. Inside there, you should not change the `SECRET_KEY` string.

Comment: Also, please, try to comment one by one any third-party apps inside your `INSTALLED_APPS` and each time run `./manage.py check`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**: According the ["get started section"](https://cqlengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#getting-started) you should run the command `/manage.py sync_table` in order for the tables to be created. Also take a look at [this post](https://ahappyknockoutmouse.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/using-cassandra-with-django-and-cqlengine-a-brief-example-from-by-project/) (if you haven't already).

Also, maybe the [django-cassandra-engine](https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine#installation) instructions might help you.

Have you added your app (where the model resides) inside your `INSTALLED_APPS` list (which lives inside your `settings.py` file)?

Like this (assuming that your app is named `stream`):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'stream.apps.StreamConfig',  # <-- this should be added
]
```

Of course, after that, you should run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Thank @nik_m, let me try it today and get back.